# Simplification idea for finding antiderivative

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Is there a simple way of finding the anti-derivative $F$ (i.e. $F(x)=\int f(x)dx$) of $$f(x)=\frac{1}{(\sqrt{x}-1)\sqrt{x}}$$

I've managed to do it by 2 *by parts integrations* in row, but that took almost 2 pages, I was just wondering if there's a simplification that I'm missing here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set $x=z^2$, so that $dx=2z\,dz$ and
$$ \int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}(\sqrt{x}-1)} = \int\frac{2\,dz}{z-1} = C+2\log(z-1) = C+2\log(\sqrt{x}-1).$$

Comment: Ahhhhh, how I could have missed this :(( thanks so much, this is very neat. (by the way my result was $2+2\log \cdots,$ so I guess $C=2$ here.

Comment: would you use the same substitution for $\int \frac{dx}{(\sqrt{x}-1)^2}?$

Comment: @user929304: I'd say so, coupled with $$\int \frac{z\,dz}{(z-1)^2}=\int\frac{dz}{z-1}+\int\frac{dz}{(z-1)^2}.$$

Comment: you're just too awesome!!

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

Let $$\sqrt x-1=y\implies\dfrac{dx}{2\sqrt x}=du$$